# Why is Ruby printing out the variable and not the string?

Tags: ruby

With the following statement

```
print @b>@d?("S";@b+=1): @b<@d?("N";@b-=1):""
```

I want `S` to be output to the screen and then the value of `b` incremented if the val of `b` is higher than `d`. Otherwise check if `b` is lower than `d` and decrement `b`.

However, it seems that the value of `b + 1` is printed instead. What is going on here?

Comment: Small is useless if you can't read it.

Comment: It's for a codingame challenge.

Comment: Right, I get that, but when people are trying to help it's nice to help them out by de-obfuscating :)

Comment: Now I get ya! didn't mean to sound snappy. Internet needs TONE, not new tech to make communication easier. That's good advice I'll keep in mind.

Comment: No worries; I didn't read any disrespect into it, nor did I mean any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ruby methods, always the last line is returned by default. Change your code to

```
print @b>@d?(@b+=1; "S"): @b<@d?(@b-=1; "N"):""
```

In order to do what you want as an output.

Answer (score 1):

The value of b+1 is the last thing returned here: `("S";@b+=1)`, thus, it is what gets evaluated by `print`. Let us try a simpler example:

```
x = 0
# => 0 
puts (true ? ("X is incremented #{x+=1}"; "Only this is printed though") : "Never here")
# Only this is printed though
# => nil 
x
# => 1
```

Although the first statement is executed, which increments `x`, only the last statement is passed as an argument to `puts`.